# Copy a set of records from one sql-server to another using c# and entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

How can I copy a customer from a CRM database to another CRM database?

My requirement is that, from (production) sql-server, I need to be able to select a customer and copy 100% of his related data to another (test) sql-server.

I already have an entity model in place which I use for my web application, I wish to use the same and read all the customer information as entities. But I am not sure, how should I use these entities and connect to another sql-server (I plan to use custom config for knowing the address of the target sql-server).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not create a backup of the original database and recreate it on the other one ?

Comment: @Maciek: My CRM is 40+ GB in size on production, so that idea is out of question.

Comment: What about doing it in a stored procedure which takes as parameter the target database and server name as well? I would prefer to do this in sql server side ( stored procedure ) because whenever you change the db schema the sp will fail or not compile anymore and will be easier to identify the reasons.

Comment: I prefer creating a server link from production to the test db, then using a stored proc to perform the transfer.

Comment: @Davide & @yodaj: Thanks for your input. I kept the sproc option as the last resort. But out of curiosity, I would still love to know the possibility to achieve such a feat using C# and EF.

Comment: Would you reconsider using the backup, copying data in the manner you suggests sounds problematic. Are there triggers, keys, identity columns, reference data that might interfere with a copy in this manner ?  Backup Process Might Be - 1. Use backups that you are already doing on a (daily basis??) 2. Truncate transaction logs 3. Zip backup file 3. Copy backup file  4. Restore backup file.   5.  Automate so process occurs overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define entity model for your customer and all related entities you want to transfer. Next you must define exactly same DB structure on your test server so that entity model can be used for both servers.

The basic scenario can be (pseudocode):

```
Customer customer = null;
using (var context = new MyContext("ProductionConnectionString"))
{
  // You must use Include to load all related data
  customer = context.Customers.Include("...").Where(...).Single();
}

using (var context= new MyContext("TestConnectionString"))
{
  context.Customers.AddObject(customer); // Inserts everything
  using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    context.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
  }
}
```

The problem will be if part of data already exists in DB. In such case you will have to first load customer from test DB and manually merge data from production customer into loaded one so that already existing data are not inserted again and modified/deleted data are updated/deleted in test db.

Comment: Thanks, the pseudo code you gave is exactly what I was thinking of to instantiate a new context with a switched connection. And the problem you try to foresee about the part of data being in the target DB should/will not happen, as I intend to add the customer from production as a new customer in test. And of course as  you rightly said the schema in both the db should be same, to handle this I already follow a versioning system in my databases, which I intend to verify before I can initiate copy of customer.

Comment: Can you also comment on the elegance & performance of the 2 approaches? As in using a sproc and the one with C# & EF? Don't know for some reason, I personally feel C# & EF based solution will give me more control and error handling and recoverability?